# Unity C# Cannot get my functions to work, when calling between scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have read a huge amount of tutorials, but cannot get this to work. Yes, I am new, so this maybe obvious. 
I have read that I should strive to keep my code separate and simple. Therefor I am trying, to no avail, to write my functions on separate scripts, and thereafter call them into my main player movement script. 
But for whatever reason, nothing happens when I press play. 
Pleeeeeease help me, and please forgive my ignorance.

best regards

**Script 1**

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 5f;
    public Vector2 move;
    public Run run;
    public Walk walk;



    void Update()
    {
        walk.Walki();
        run.Sprint();

    }
```

**Script 2**

```
public class Walk : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float speed;
    public Vector3 move;
    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        speed = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Movement>().speed;
    }
    public void Walki()
    {

        float mLeft = 1f;
        float mRight = -1f;

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(mLeft, mRight, 0f);

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            rb.transform.position += new Vector3(mLeft, 0f, 0f) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            rb.transform.position += new Vector3(mRight, 0f, 0f) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide the actual code, not a screenshot. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When asking you need to copy the error message or more details about what happened. It's hard to figure out what's going on, but looking at your code there isn't much reason to keep this separate. Put this together in one script and separate it out later when you need to and have a better understanding of how you need your components to interact

Comment: I don't see any issues besides that symbol that you said was a mistake during screenshotting.  However, as already stated please include the actual code, and any errors you are getting?   Did you also make sure the script is attached to your player and that you have assigned them correctly?  From your movement script I dont see a getcomponent call so are you assigning it in the editor?

Comment: I am not getting any console errors, and both scripts are attached to my player object.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update(){
     gameObject.GetComponent<Walk>().Walkie();
}
```

You could try to call it like this and write a Debug.Log("walks") inside your Warkie method.